# Building two tables with relation fails

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am trying to build up two tables and a relationship between them in a Xamarin cross plattform application. Here's the code for the tables:

```
[Table("DetailTypes")]
public class DetailType
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("DateDetails")]
public class DateDetail
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID_Date { get; set; }

    public string Wert { get; set; }

    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(DetailType))]
    public int DetailTypeId { get; set; }

    [OneToOne]
    public DetailType DetailType { get; set; }
}
```

The tables are created in code as follows:

```
    public ItemDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

        database.CreateTableAsync<DateDetail>().Wait(); //Error is thrown here
        database.CreateTableAsync<DetailType>().Wait(); 
    }
```

When running the code I get the error "An unhandled exception occured." in the marked line. The first table is created at that point. What am I doing wrong?

Another question: Is it important to create the tables in a certain order as they are dependent on eachother?

**EDIT:**

StackTrace of the exception (System.NotSupportedException):

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 at ***.CODE.Data.ItemDatabase..ctor (System.String dbPath) [0x00028] in D:\CODE_COPY\EigeneProjekte\CN_***_Xamarin*********\CODE\Data\ItemDatabase.cs:22

**EDIT 2:**
If I take a closer look at the Exception I find the following message:

```
Don't know about XXX.CODE.Models.DetailType
```

This is understandable, as the table DetailType has not been built at that this point. But how am I supposed to create relations via ORM then? Is there a possibility to create all tables at once to ensure that the relations are correct and no table is missing?

Comment: use a try/catch to get the actual exception

Comment: Does that exception have a cause? Because it doesn't say anything useful

Comment: @redent84 Sorry for my late answer and thanks for trying to help. I´ve updated my question, could you have a look please? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relationship annotations inherit from SQLite-Net `Ignore` attribute so the inner layer of SQLite-Net ignores this attribute it's correctly processed by sqlite-net-extensions. If SQLite-Net is not recognizing the `Ignore` annotation it's probably because there are conflicting versions of SQLite-Net installed as dependencies.

TL;DR: Check your dependencies and remove any duplicated SQLite-Net library

Depending on the platform, it may be easier to remove the sqlite-net-extensions nuget package and simply copy the sources to the project.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can make more than 1 table in a [single call](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/89a5a766f156b400ab6924e97d08ffe22f8cbe6b/src/SQLite.Net.Async/SQLiteAsyncConnection.cs#L109)
But as it [iteates through provided](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/89a5a766f156b400ab6924e97d08ffe22f8cbe6b/src/SQLite.Net.Async/SQLiteAsyncConnection.cs#L131) types and calls function for each type separately, you have to define the sequense yourself